# How to intersect layers that do not completely overlap in QGIS?

Tags: layers, overlapping-features, land-use

I have two layers in QGIS that I want to intersect in a specific way.

On one side I have a layer of the different biotope types in the city of Berlin. On the other side I have a layer of the different land uses inside the city of Berlin.

The shape of individual biotopes does not overlap with the shape individual land uses. This makes sense because biotopes and land uses are not defined by the same parameters, so they never overlap.

I would like to know how to do the following: For each individual biotope, I would like to know what different land uses are present in it.

For instance, a specific humid grassland located at the north of the city has 25% of residential land use and 75% of brownfield land use.

Is it possible to view the results showing which proportion of land uses constitute each of the individual biotopes?

Comment: Saying 'they never overlap' is a bit confusing. Do you mean they don't align? Have you tried using the intersect tool? The output of intersect will be the overlapping parts of the two input features and it's attribute table will contain attributes from both input layers. You can calculate the areas of these overlapping parts and areas of the input land use features to produce the % figures you need.